# App.config can't find my element

Tags: c#, app-config

I have a simple `app.config` file that doesn't quite pass the IDEs checker.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="XmlRoot" type="System.String"/>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <omitted/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
  </startup>
  <XmlRoot>
    <add key="relativepath" value=""/>
  </XmlRoot>
</configuration>
```

I added the `<section name="XmlRoot" type="System.String" />` part to the config and then I tried to define the name and key here: `<add key="relativepath" value=""/>`. But for some reason the IDE gives me the following Messages:

[image]

I rarely use the app.config file so it could just be a noob mistake. How do I make it recognize my tags?

Comment: Are you just trying to add a configuration value for your program to pick up and use? If so, you should just put it in the `<appSettings>` section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's just a simple string, you can use [AppSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings(v=vs.110).aspx) to accomplish this.

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="relativepath" value="mypath" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Access it from C# like this:

```
string path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["relativepath"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your type to `System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler`

this is how I define my sections:

```
<configSections>
<sectionGroup name="MySettings">
  <section name="serverConfiguration" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler"></section>
  <section name="sqlSettings" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler"></section>
</sectionGroup>    
 </configSections>
```

...

```
<MySettings>
<sqlSettings>
  <add key="sqlTransactionTimeOut" value="0" />
</sqlSettings>
<serverConfiguration>      
  <add key="resolveDnsAsync" value="true" />
</serverConfiguration>
</MySettings>
```

Answer (score -1):

Probably you need to use the section appSettings

```
<configuration>
     <appSettings> 
         <!-- and Here you define the key and the value like you do-->
         <add key="relativepath" value="path"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

then in your code write something like this to read it.

```
String path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["relativepath"].ToString();
```

hope it works for you.

:)